# Balancing Permanent Government Employment and Private Job Training

Tags: halal-haram

Assalam o alaikum, i am working at a private company which doesn't allow us to do two jobs at a time,. I also have a government job and that is permanent and my private job is 18 months training. My parents and my future inlaws want me to do both jobs by applying for medical leave from govt job until 18 month period ends. So the salary from my govt job will be haram? And what should i do? Should i just resign?

Comment: Your salary is halal as long as the actual work you do is halal.

Comment: Other than that we do not give personal advice. Nor are we qualified to give legal advice, especially when the agreement terms and other details are not known to us. You should consult a lawyer and a mufti.